# How to inherit from custom control in same module using XAML?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, c++-cx

I'm trying to inherit from a control I've written in a project (using XAML). I've tried with a blank page and I can't even get that to work:

```
<local:BlankPage
    x:Class="MyNamespace.MyPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:MyNamespace"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
    </Grid>
</local:BlankPage>
```

`BlankPage` is just a new blank page derived class I created via the wizard. `MyPage` is the same. The error I get is:

> The type 'local:BlankPage' was not found. Verify that you are not
>   missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have
>   been built.

How do I do inheritance in XAML for WinRT / Windows Store Apps?

Comment: Have you built the project?  If the project is built, does the namespace match the name of the metadata file that gets built (or, at a minimum, is the name of the metadata file a prefix of the namespace name)?  (By default, the metadata file has the same name as the project.)

Comment: Hi, yes, the project is built, and they both use the same namespace. I could get it to work by including BlankPage.xaml.h in MyPage.xaml.h. But that seems like a hack!

Comment: Never screw w/an `h` file. It's not only a hack, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your XAML:

```
<local:BlankPage
```

You are declaring that you want it to instantiate BlankPage, but what you really want is to instantiate your custom MyPage. So it *should* read:

```
<local:MyPage
```

Assuming that MyPage is in the `local` namespace.

And, that's it!

Comment: I'm trying to achieve XAML inheritance, i.e. `MyPage` inherits from `BlankPage`.